# How to get the number of shards being used in the cluster - Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, aws-elasticsearch

I am creating a lambda function which will hold a python script. The purpose of the lambda function is to alert if shards usage in a cluster is greater than 90% i.e. 4500/5000 shards being used.
I am using an ElasticSearch client for python so I want to know if there's any methods that allow you to calculate open shards capacity. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this [Elasticsearch library](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.12.0/index.html) and run something along the lines of:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
stats = es.cluster.stats()
shards = stats['indices']['shards']['total']
```

It uses this [stats method](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.12.0/api.html#elasticsearch.client.ClusterClient.stats) to get the clusters' stats, from there you can get all the info you need about number of shards across all indices.

If you want to calculate the max threshold of shards and notify based on some % of usage, find your max number of shards/node, get the number of nodes from `stats`, calculate max threshold, and check if you need to notify with something like that `notify = shards/max > 0.9`.

EDIT:

Here's a more complete code example:

```
threshold = 0.9
cluster_stats = es.cluster.stats()
cluster_settings = es.cluster.get_settings()
total_shards = cluster_stats['indices']['shards']['total']
data_nodes = cluster_stats['nodes']['count']['data']
max_shards_node = int(cluster_settings['persistent']['cluster']['max_shards_per_node'])
# Calculate if the current amount of shards is approaching the threshold
notify = total_shards/(data_nodes * max_shards_node) > threshold
if notify:
    # you choose how to handle notification
```

Comment: is there any way we can programmatically find max shards allowed in a cluster without the need of hard coding the value? 

I tried cluster stats but I don't think you can find max shards allowed per node for the whole cluster

Comment: You can calculate the maximum number of shards if you get the number of data nodes you have and the maximum shards per node (both can be found in cluster stats) and multiply the two.

Comment: I am not sure how you can check max shards per node in cluster stats. I don't see it anywhere. Can you please tell me which key name

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer I posted, it is using the Elasticsearch service from aws though, so it might be different for you if you’re hosting it yourself.